# hyperbolic function simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

In taking a derivative, I end up with this epression:

$e^x*(1-e^x)-(1+e^x)*(-e^x) / (1-e^x)^2$

However, from a calculator I see that the first line simplifies in nicer, simpler expression:

$1/cosh(x)-1$

I don't have yet a knowledge of hyperbolic functions. Could you show me and explain me this simplification, please?

Comment: how did you go  from $\mathrm{e}^x*(1-\mathrm{e}^x)\to \mathrm{e}^x/(1-\mathrm{e}^x)$?

Comment: you can ignore the second step and focus on the first and the third. Perhaps, I should delete the second, which might be misleading. However, I just apply an algrebraic property; namely, I split the expression in 2. The denominator (1-e^x)^2 simplifies with (1-e^x)

Comment: ok. that is still not making any sense to me that, but it is not that uncommon for this to be the case ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are going from 
$$
g(x) = \dfrac{1+\mathrm{e}^x}{1-\mathrm{e}^x}
$$
and taking the derivative?

in any case
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^x}{1-\mathrm{e}^x}+\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^x(1+\mathrm{e}^x)}{(1-\mathrm{e}^x)^2}=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^x(1-\mathrm{e}^x) +\mathrm{e}^x(1+\mathrm{e}^x)}{(1-\mathrm{e}^x)^2}= \dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^x}{(1-\mathrm{e}^x)^2}
$$
this equivalent to
$$
\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^x}{1-2\mathrm{e}^x+\mathrm{e}^{2x}}= \frac{2\mathrm{e}^{x}}{2\mathrm{e}^{x}\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}+\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{2}-1\right)}=\dfrac{1}{\cosh(x)-1}
$$

Comment: yes, taking that derivative!

Comment: good good. You should put brackets around the denominator in your question (It took me some time to realise it was not $\left(1/\cosh(x)\right) - 1$ .

Comment: I don't get hw you get: 2e^x/(1-e^x)^2. Why (1+e^2) cancel out?

Comment: I put both terms with same denominator and then I expand. See edit.

Comment: I don't get how 2e^x can stay alone at the numerator at the third step